# Efficient algorithm for eliminating "dominated" matrix rows

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Consider the generic matrix $A$,

$$\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\cdots&a_{mn}\\}$$

where each $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$. I'll say that row $k$ "dominates" row $l$ if $\forall j\le n: a_{kj} \ge a_{lj}$ (please correct my terminology here).

I would like to generate a new matrix $B$ which is the same as $A$, except that all the dominated rows are removed. I have a large matrix ($A$) with a hundred million entries or so and would like to transform it to a smaller matrix ($B$) to save computing time on subsequent operations. I'm looking for a computationally efficient algorithm for accomplishing this.

References and terminology are appreciated.

Comment: Hello! I've used some MathJax tricks to improve the ellipses in a way I think you'll appreciate $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor thanks!

Comment: No problem, my friend $\ddot\smile$